# C# dataGridView combobox AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a dataGridView with AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle

All fine, one row white, next grey for all columns.

But now I added a column of `DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton` and for this column only the color is not alternating per row.

Any hint how to alternate also the row column in the column with combobox?

Comment: This is one of those occasions where a screenshot or two would be appropriate.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do with the standard column. I haven't looked but I would assume that the cell uses either the `ControlPaint` class or the `ComboBoxRenderer` class to draw the appearance of a `ComboBox` control. The cell background colour actually is correct, but that "control" is drawn over the top of that. I suspect that you would have to create a custom cell and handle that rendering yourself. The `ComboBoxRenderer` class has a `DrawTextBox` method that doesn't allow you to specify a colour, so I'm guessing that's what's being used.

Comment: If you handle the rendering yourself, you could call `DrawDropDownButton` but not `DrawTextBox`, so the cell background would not be covered. You'd then have to draw the text yourself too.

Comment: Note that the .NET source code is visible to the public so you can actually see how the standard cell class does its rendering. Creating a custom cell is not for the faint of heart though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this doing the following:

1. Using Visual Studio designer, edit the columns, set the combobox column DisplayStyle to "Nothing". This is necessary to allow the applied colors to show through.
2. Using something similar to the following code in the CellFormatting method of the DataGridView:

   ```
            if (e.ColumnIndex == #YourComboboxColumnIndex#)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)#YourDatagridViewName#.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[#YourComboboxColumnIndex#];
                cell.Style.BackColor = (e.RowIndex % 2 == 0) ? Color.White : Color.FromArgb(192, 255, 192) ;
            }
   ```

**Note:** Make sure to apply the white BackColor.  Otherwise, some "funky" stuff bleeds through the "Nothing" DisplayStyle.